# Django: media files doesn't load up uploaded by user in production environment

Tags: django, web, hosting, production-environment

I'm hosting my site in railway. Everything is set up and works fine but the images uploaded by user don't load up.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path. join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics")
```

blog.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% static "images/projects" as baseUrl %}

{% for post in post_list %}
 <div class="image_wrapper"><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}" target="_parent"><img
                    src="{{ post.img.url }}" alt="image 1"/></a></div>

 {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Not Found: /media/pics/CC_Tech_Computers_1_6rgae2m.jpg
Not Found: /media/pics/CC_Tech_Computers_1_6rgae2m.jpg
Not Found: /media/pics/CC_Tech_Computers_1_6rgae2m.jpg
Not Found: /media/pics/CC_Tech_Computers_1_6rgae2m.jpg
```

Comment: how do you init BASE_DIR?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
src="{{ post.img.url }}"
```

Try this way:

```
src="/media/pics/post.img"
```

And in your `models.py`:

```
img = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics/") #Here added `forward slash (/)`
```

Try this way and see if it loads the image